# ASMX Web Service that returns image

Tags: asp.net, asmx

I want an .asmx service that returns a .png file. My problem is, my web application is hosted on GoDaddy. Because of this, I can't edit the web.config file. If I could edit the web.config file, I would simply created an HTTP Handler.

My question is, is there a way to have an .asmx that returns an image? If so, how?

Comment: Why would you have to edit the web.config file to use a handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply have the service return the image as a byte array (`byte[]`).

I have no idea why you think you should edit the web.config.

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on how you want to use the image.
If you chose to return a byte array like John suggests, there will be a huge overhead for serializing that to xml (or json), something like 13-15 times (for xml).

I'd suggest that you create a Generic Handler (.ashx) with a query string arg referring to the image, and write directly to the response stream.

Then in your web service, in place of the image, return the url to the handler with proper query string.  The consumer of the service can then be responsible for getting the image.

Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to return an image from a web service is probably just to return it either as a byte array or as a custom type which includes a byte array (as well as other information, such as image type or suggested file name, etc.).

When you say you want it to return an image, what exactly are you expecting?  Do you expect an image in the way that an image renders in a web browser when linked?  If so, you're going to have to manually manipulate the output.  There are plenty of tutorials online about "displaying an image from a database in asp .net" which would help you.

Basically, you'd hijack the response and change its headers, write the binary image data, and end the response.  It works well enough on a web page, but I've never tried it on a web service.  It would, however, be considered poor form for a web service to do this.  It would break the "contract" of the web service.  (Which is why I'm hoping, and at least assuming, that this is not the desired effect.)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a handler that returns a PNG file, use an .ashx file. If you want a service with a method that returns a PNG file, convert the PNG to a byte array first and return the array.